# I'm getting an SQL syntax error and I'm not sure what's happening

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

**Edit:** fixed something with a comma, but I'm still getting the error

I've been stressing over this SQL query for three days.

```
CREATE TABLE status_likes (
  username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (username,id),
  FOREIGN KEY id REFERENCES status (id),
  FOREIGN KEY username REFERENCES users (username)
)
```

It keeps giving me this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'REFERENCES `status` (`id`) FOREIGN KEY username REFERENCES users
>   (username), ' at line 5

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Thanks!

Comment: You have an extra comma on the last line of the `create table` statement.

Comment: which actually should be at the end of the previous line

Comment: Did that, but I'm still getting that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column names in an index have to be in parentheses. You were also missing a comma after the first `FOREIGN KEY`, and had an extra comma after the second one.

```
CREATE TABLE status_likes (
  username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (username,id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES status (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username)
)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6792)

Comment: Thank you so much! My timer hasn't expired yet so I can't mark you as correct, but I will when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `,` after last line of CREATE statement having `FOREIGN KEY username REFERENCES users (username),`

```
CREATE TABLE status_likes (
  username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (username,id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES status (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username)
)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm still getting it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,Remove comma.

```
CREATE TABLE status_likes (
  username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (username,id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES status (id)
  FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username)
)
```

Comment: MyISAM does not support FK.